# Overlong Object Manipulation for Order Form

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, javascript-objects

I'm trying to write an order form for a food delivery website (to learn more about objects in Javascript), so that each item, when selected, populates an array. It should also recognise the quantity requested, if an item is clicked twice, and not create a duplicate. This is my code, which works, but seems overlong. In particular, my final for loop, for increasing quantity, seems as if it should be superfluous. Is there a smarter way doing this?

The JSON data I'm drawing from looks like this:

```
"dishes": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "Jumbo Chicken Wings",
      "description": "Honey, Ginger, Chilli, Soy",
      "price": "4.50"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "name": "Spiced Whitebait",
      "description": "Lemon Mayonaise",
      "price": "5"
    }
```

And this is my (probably overlong) code:

```
// ORDER FORM

// begin with empty array
var orderform = [];

function chooseDish() {

  // when clicking on item...
  $("#menu li").click(function(){

    //create new object from item listed properties
    var item = {
      id: $(this).attr('id'),
      dish: $(this).find("span.dish-name").text(),
      price: $(this).find("span.dish-price").text()
    };

    // either add first item to array...
    if (!orderform.length) {
      item.quantity = 1;
      orderform.push(item);
    }

    // or see if an object is already in the array.
    else {
      var hasDishBeenSelected = false;
      for (var i = 0; i < orderform.length; i++) {
        if (orderform[i].id === item.id) {
          hasDishBeenSelected = true;
        }
      } 

      // if the item hasn't already been selected add the item...
      if (!hasDishBeenSelected) {
        item.quantity = 1;
        orderform.push(item);
      }

      // otherwise increase that item's quantity by 1
      else {
        for (var j = 0; j < orderform.length; j++) {
          if (orderform[j].id === item.id) {
            orderform[j].quantity += 1;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    console.table(orderform);
  });
}
```

Thanks for any tips!